# PrestaShop Module unit tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, prestashop

I am new in PrestaShop and I need to create custom module, with XML files parsing and database operations. I would like to create unit test for this module, because I don't want to test it 'by hand'. Could you provide me any advices, methods or articles on the Web about the patterns how to do it well? I can't find good tutorial using web search engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did write a blog post about testing prestashop with Mink and Behat (Cucumber equivalent) which you can read here - http://xavierriley.co.uk/blog/2012/10/12/test-driving-prestashop-with-behat/

There's also this pull request on Github for adding unit tests to the project - https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/70

The tooling for testing things like this in PHP doesn't seem to be as mature as the Ruby/Java equivalents so don't get your hopes up, but that should be a start.

Comment: Thank you for useful stuff! I have already done some unit tests for my custom module by taking advantage of good software architecture patterns. I have implemented my module with applying object-oriented constructions, loose class coupling, interfaces and abstraction (separate XML and DB access classes with its own interfaces). Then all component are glued together in module root class in dependency injection manner. Afterwards, I have utilized PHPUnit to write and run unit test, I have written a few mock classes to use in place of XML and DB access classes. Now I have quite testable module.

Comment: The link for your blog post is down, any chance to repost it?

Comment: @CIRCLE https://web.archive.org/web/20130706031033/https://www.xavierriley.co.uk/blog/2012/10/12/test-driving-prestashop-with-behat/